# a-frame vr how to drag and drop assets / elements insight a picture?

Tags: aframe, webvr

I am trying out a-frame and can't find anything about how to drag and drop elements and have been looking for it for hours! Is anyone familiar with a-frame?
Thanks

thats my code so far:

```
<a-scene>
    <a-cursor></a-cursor>
 <a-assets>
  <img id="enemy-sprite" crossorigin="" src="mustache1.jpg">
 </a-assets>
 <a-image look-at="#player" src="#enemy-sprite" transparent="true" position="0 1.8 -4"></a-image>
 <a-camera id="player" position="0 1.8 0"></a-camera>
 <a-sky src="street.jpg"></a-sky>
```

EDIT:
browser/home.html:

```
  <scene scene-id="sceneId"></scene>
```

browser/js/app/directives/screne.html:

```
  <a-scene>
    <a-sphere click-drag position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
    <a-camera look-controls-enabled="false"></a-camera>
  </a-scene>
```

index.html

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-click-drag-component"></script>
<script>  registerAframeClickDragComponent(window.AFRAME); </script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't built into Aframe, but you can use a 3rd party component to get the desired results.

[`aframe-click-drag-component`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-click-drag-component) allows for clicking and dragging entities around on the screen:

> Entities with the `click-drag` component can be click and dragged around the 3D scene. Even works while the camera is moving or rotating!
>
> ```html
> <head>
>   <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
>   <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-click-drag-component"></script>
>   <script>
>     registerAframeClickDragComponent(window.AFRAME);
>   </script>
> </head>
>
> <body>
>   <a-scene>
>     <a-sphere click-drag position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
>     <a-camera look-controls-enabled="false"></a-camera>
>   </a-scene>
> </body>
> ```

Check out [the demo](https://jesstelford.github.io/aframe-click-drag-component/).

Comment: Thank you. Are you familiar with the drawing component? I tried to npm install it and then require it (var AFRAME = require("aframe-core");
var draw = require("aframe-draw-component").component;
AFRAME.registerComponent("draw", draw);) but I keep getting the error message that AFRAME is not defined

Comment: Try using aframe, not aframe-core.

Comment: Hey, your answer was great and back then drag and drop started working but now not anymore and I can't tell why. I updated my question with the code, would be great if you could help. Been researching for so long but there is not much online for a-frame..Did it just like you suggested and can't move the object and neither 'move' the screen..its all just static..

Comment: I am following the installation instructions exactly and am getting this error in the console.


v-tour-embed:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: registerAframeClickDragComponent is not defined
    at v-tour-embed:10

Comment: @SpencerCooley See here : https://github.com/jesstelford/aframe-click-drag-component/issues/17